# Consulta Lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

tenho a seguinte consulta em `T-SQL`:

```sql
 SELECT TOP (60) COUNT(*) AS QTD, SUM(Duration) AS Total, AVG(Duration) AS Media, MIN(Duration) AS Menor, LEFT (TextData, 80) AS TextData
        FROM Traces WITH (nolock)
        WHERE (StartTime >= DATEADD(D, - 7, GETDATE())) AND (DataBaseName IN ('databaseName1', 'databaseName2'))  
        GROUP BY TextData, DataBaseName
        HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1) ORDER BY Total DESC
```

Estou tentando escrever em Lambda, não gostaria de `Linq`, só se for o último caso.

**Como montar?**
tenho dúvidas quando ao `LEFT` e ao `HAVING`:

essa é minha consulta por enquanto.

```cs
 using (var ctx = new TracesEntity())
        {
            var lambda = ctx.TraceTabelas.Where(q => q.DataBaseName == "databaseName1" || q.DataBaseName == "databaseName2")
                .GroupBy(a => new { a.TextData, a.DataBaseName })
                .Select(b => new { 
                                    QTD = b.Count(), 
                                    Total = b.Sum(b1 => b1.Duration),
                                    Media = b.Average(b1 => b1.Duration),
                                    Menor = b.Min(b1 => b1.Duration),
                                    TextData = b.Select(b1 => b1.TextData)
                                })
                .Take(60)
                .OrderByDescending(b =>b.Total)
                .ToList();

            GridView1.DataSource = lambda;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: Você deveria ordenar primeiro e depois dar o `take`

Comment: Eu recomendaria muito que você mantivesse esse tipo de consulta no banco, através de `Stored Procedures` para ganhar performance na consulta ao invés de ter q fazer as relações no código assim.

Comment: lambda não tem uma perfomance boa? claro que muitas coisas já esta em stored procedure, mas não da pra criar tudo..até pq isso é uma page que é executada apenas 1 vez ao dia.

Comment: Como está o resultado até então?

Comment: textData não esta vindo..e deve estar errado outras coisas, por exemplo onde faço o having???, existe como em debug eu verificar qual a consulta ele esta montando em TSQL ?

Comment: Tem. Retire o `ToList()` e o `Take(60)`. `lambda` receberá um objeto de consulta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pra fazer o equivalente ao `having` no SQL no [linq](/questions/tagged/linq), basta colocar um `Where()` após o `GroupBy()`:

```cs
using (var ctx = new TracesEntity())
{
    var lambda = ctx.TraceTabelas.Where(q => q.DataBaseName == "megacorretor" || q.DataBaseName == "stats_mega")
        .GroupBy(a => new { a.TextData, a.DataBaseName })
        .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
        .Select(b => new { 
                            QTD = b.Count(), 
                            Total = b.Sum(b1 => b1.Duration),
                            Media = b.Average(b1 => b1.Duration),
                            Menor = b.Min(b1 => b1.Duration),
                            TextData = b.Select(b1 => b1.TextData).ToString().Substring(0,20)
                        })
        .Take(60)
        .OrderByDescending(b =>b.Total)
        .ToList();

    GridView1.DataSource = lambda;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: só para completar faltou o () no cout, depois que coloquei funcionou
`Where(group => group.Count() > 1)`

Comment: Ah, sim. Desculpe. Escrevi a solução direto aqui e não testei. Valeu!

Answer (score 2):

Faltou só uma última resposta a minha pergunta que era o LEFT que resolvi com Substring

```
 TextData = b.Select(b1 => b1.TextData).ToString().Substring(0,20)
```

Comment: Vou complementar a sentença da minha resposta com esta, ok?